# How to access a file that my app downloaded in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, firebase, file, firebase-storage

Im writing an app that makes an XML file, uploads it to Firebase Storage, and is then supposed to download that file from Firebase, and read it.
I've managed to get to the downloading part (under the name "RecipeDown.xml"), but after that I don't know how to access the file i downloaded in order to read it.

Here's how I download from Firebase:

```
fDownRef = fStorage.child(lastUploaded);
fDownRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        String strUrl = uri.toString();
        Toast.makeText(ExEmElFormat.this, "Downloading...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        downloadFiles(ExEmElFormat.this, "RecipeDown", ".xml", ExEmElFormat.this.getFilesDir().getPath(), strUrl);
        readXML();


    }
```

downloadFiles() Method:

```
public void downloadFiles(Context context, String fileName, String fileExtenstion, String destinationDirectory, String url){

    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, destinationDirectory, fileName + fileExtenstion);

    downloadManager.enqueue(request);
}
```

readXML() Method:

```
public void readXML(){
    try {
        fis= openFileInput("RecipeDown.xml");
        isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line = br.readLine();
        String[] lines = new String[3];
        int i = 0;
        while (i<3) {
            sb.append(line+'\n');
            line = br.readLine();
            lines[i] = line;
            i++;
        }
        String new_name = lines[0].substring(lines[0].indexOf('=')+2, lines[0].indexOf('>')-1);
        String new_ing = lines[1].substring(lines[1].indexOf('=')+2, lines[1].indexOf('>')-2);
        String new_steps = lines[2].substring(lines[2].indexOf('=')+2, lines[2].indexOf('>')-2);

        nameET.setText(new_name);
        ingredientsET.setText(new_ing);
        stepsET.setText(new_steps);







    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    File xmlf = new File(this.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/RecipeDown.xml");
    System.out.println("XMLF:" + xmlf.exists());

}
```

System Print:
`I/System.out: XMLF:false`

I'm trying to access a file my app downloaded, but can't even though I can find it the phone's files.

Comment: You are combining getFilesDir() with setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(). That is not possible.

Comment: `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, destinationDirectory, fileName + fileExtenstion);` Change to: `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, "MyDir", fileName + fileExtenstion);`.

Comment: `fis= openFileInput("RecipeDown.xml");` Change to `File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir("MyDir", "RecipeDown.xml"); fis= new FileInputStream(file);`

Comment: Hey, first of all thanks for your help! i think i get my error now. however, the line
  File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir("MyDir", "RecipeDown.xml");
raises an error bc i dont have a method called getExternalFilesDir. what to do?

Comment: Just a typo. I forgot a ).

Comment: No method? Then place ExEmElFormat.this. before it. Just as you did with getFilesDir().

Comment: You're a life saver!! Everything works great now. I can't express my gratitude enough. I was stuck on this for 2 days and had to get it done by today. have a blessed day.